# Hide checkout fields when selecting multiple delivery methods in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I use code that hides the checkout fields if the Local Pickup shipping method is selected:

```
    // Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {

    // HERE your shipping methods rate IDs
    $local_pickup = 'local_pickup:3';
    $pickpoint = 'wc_custom_shipping_pickpoint';

    $required_text = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
    $required_html = '<abbr class="required" title="' . $required_text . '">*</abbr>';
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var ism = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',         ismc = ism+':checked',
                csa = 'input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox',
                rq = '-required',       vr = 'validate'+rq,     w = 'woocommerce',      wv = w+'-validated',
                iv = '-invalid',        fi = '-field',          wir = w+iv+' '+w+iv+rq+fi,
                b = '#billing_',        s = '#shipping_',       f = '_field',
                a1 = 'country',     a2 = 'address_1',   a3 = 'address_2',   a4 = 'postcode',    a5 = 'state',   a6 = 'city',
                b1 = b+a1+f,        b2 = b+a2+f,        b3 = b+a3+f,        b4 = b+a4+f,        b5 = b+a5+f,    b6 = b+a6+f,
                s1 = s+a1+f,        s2 = s+a2+f,        s3 = s+a3+f,        s4 = s+a4+f,        s5 = s+a5+f,    s6 = s+a6+f,
                pickPoint = '<?php echo $pickpoint; ?>',        localPickup = '<?php echo $local_pickup; ?>';

            // Utility function to shows or hide checkout fields
            function showHide( action='show', selector='' ){
                if( action == 'show' )
                    $(selector).show(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() == undefined )
                            $(selector+' label').append('<?php echo $required_html; ?>');
                    });
                else
                    $(selector).hide(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined )
                            $(selector+' label > .required').remove();
                    });
            }

            // Initializing at start after checkout init (Based on the chosen shipping method)
            setTimeout(function(){
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint ) // Chosen "Pick point" (Hiding "Delivery")
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1 ); // Country
                    showHide('hide',b2 ); // Address 1
                    showHide('hide',b3 ); // Address 2
                    showHide('hide',b4 ); // Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5 ); // State
                    showHide('hide',b6 ); // City
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup ) // Choosen "Local pickup" (Hidding "Take away")
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);
                }
            }, 100);

            // When shipping method is changed (Live event)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', ism, function() {
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('show',s2);
                        showHide('show',s3);
                        showHide('show',s4);
                        showHide('show',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
            });

            // When "shipping to different address" is changed (Live event)
            $(csa).click( function() {
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint && $(this).prop('checked') )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup && $(this).prop('checked') )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('show',s2);
                    showHide('show',s3);
                    showHide('show',s4);
                    showHide('show',s5);
                    showHide('show',s6);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

The problem is that I can't do this for multiple delivery methods. I need to specify `local_pickup:3`, `local_pickup:6` and `local_pickup:9`. Hiding fields only works correctly with one specified delivery method.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code does not make fileds not required. Only solution I've found to work around is fill up hidden fields with placeholder value.

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {
    
    // HERE your shipping methods rate IDs
    $local_pickup  = array('inpost_paczkomaty:15');
    $required_text = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
    $required_html = '<abbr class="required" title="' . $required_text . '">*</abbr>';
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var ism = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',         
                ismc = ism+':checked',
                csa = 'input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox',
                rq = '-required',       
                vr = 'validate'+rq,     
                w = 'woocommerce',      
                wv = w+'-validated',
                iv = '-invalid',        
                fi = '-field',          
                wir = w+iv+' '+w+iv+rq+fi,
                b = '#billing_',        
                s = '#shipping_',       
                f = '_field',
                a1 = 'country', a2 = 'address_1', a3 = 'address_2', a4 = 'postcode', a5 = 'state', a6 = 'city',
                b1 = b+a1+f, b2 = b+a2+f, b3 = b+a3+f, b4 = b+a4+f, b5 = b+a5+f, b6 = b+a6+f,
                s1 = s+a1+f, s2 = s+a2+f, s3 = s+a3+f, s4 = s+a4+f, s5 = s+a5+f, s6 = s+a6+f,
                localPickup = '<?php echo json_encode($local_pickup); ?>';

            // Utility function to shows or hide checkout fields
            function showHide( action='show', selector='' ){
                if( action == 'show' ){
                    $(selector).show(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() == undefined )
                            $(selector+' label').append('<?php echo $required_html; ?>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $(selector).hide(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        $(this).find("[type='text']").val('00-000');
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined ){
                            $(selector+' label > .required').remove();
                        }     
                    });
                }
            }

            // Initializing at start after checkout init (Based on the chosen shipping method)
            setTimeout(function(){
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) ){ // Choosen "Local pickup" (Hidding "Take away")
                    showHide('hide',b1); //Country
                    showHide('hide',b2); //Address line 1
                    showHide('hide',b3); //Address line 2
                    showHide('hide',b4); //Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5); //State
                    showHide('hide',b6); //City
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1); //Country
                    showHide('show',b2); //Address line 1
                    showHide('hide',b3); //Address line 2
                    showHide('show',b4); //Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5); //State
                    showHide('show',b6); //City
                }
            }, 100);

            // When shipping method is changed (Live event)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', ism, function() {
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) ){
                    showHide('hide',b1); //Country
                    showHide('hide',b2); //Address line 1
                    showHide('hide',b3); //Address line 2
                    showHide('hide',b4); //Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5); //State
                    showHide('hide',b6); //City

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1); //Country
                    showHide('show',b2); //Address line 1
                    showHide('hide',b3); //Address line 2
                    showHide('show',b4); //Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5); //State
                    showHide('show',b6); //City

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
            });

            // When "shipping to different address" is changed (Live event)
            $(csa).click( function() {
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) && $(this).prop('checked') ){
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('show',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('show',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('show',s6);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. Your answer fits, too. Only for a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define multiple delivery methods in the array.

Define array like this

```
$local_pickup  = array( 'flat_rate:2','flat_rate:7' );
```

Now, where you compare `$(ismc).val() == localPickup` replace with below code. You have to find the selected method in the array so you can use `includes`.

```
localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() )
```

Complete code.

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {

    // HERE your shipping methods rate IDs
    $local_pickup  = array('flat_rate:2','flat_rate:7');
    $required_text = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
    $required_html = '<abbr class="required" title="' . $required_text . '">*</abbr>';
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var ism  = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',         
                ismc = ism+':checked',
                csa  = 'input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox',
                rq   = '-required',       
                vr   = 'validate'+rq,     
                w    = 'woocommerce',      
                wv   = w+'-validated',
                iv   = '-invalid',        
                fi   = '-field',          
                wir  = w+iv+' '+w+iv+rq+fi,
                b    = '#billing_',        
                s    = '#shipping_',       
                f    = '_field',
                a1   = 'country',     
                a2   = 'address_1',   
                a3   = 'address_2',   
                a4   = 'postcode',    
                a5   = 'state',   
                a6   = 'city',
                b1   = b+a1+f,        
                b2   = b+a2+f,        
                b3   = b+a3+f,        
                b4   = b+a4+f,        
                b5   = b+a5+f,    
                b6   = b+a6+f,
                s1   = s+a1+f,        
                s2   = s+a2+f,        
                s3   = s+a3+f,        
                s4   = s+a4+f,        
                s5   = s+a5+f,    
                s6   = s+a6+f,
                localPickup = '<?php echo json_encode($local_pickup); ?>';

            // Utility function to shows or hide checkout fields
            function showHide( action='show', selector='' ){
                if( action == 'show' )
                    $(selector).show(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() == undefined )
                            $(selector+' label').append('<?php echo $required_html; ?>');
                    });
                else
                    $(selector).hide(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined )
                            $(selector+' label > .required').remove();
                    });
            }

            // Initializing at start after checkout init (Based on the chosen shipping method)
            setTimeout(function(){
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) ){ // Choosen "Local pickup" (Hidding "Take away")
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);
                }
            }, 100);

            // When shipping method is changed (Live event)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', ism, function() {
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) ){
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('show',s2);
                        showHide('show',s3);
                        showHide('show',s4);
                        showHide('show',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
            });

            // When "shipping to different address" is changed (Live event)
            $(csa).click( function() {
                if( localPickup.includes( $(ismc).val() ) && $(this).prop('checked') ){
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }else{
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('show',s2);
                    showHide('show',s3);
                    showHide('show',s4);
                    showHide('show',s5);
                    showHide('show',s6);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help! Everything is working perfectly. Your bounty will only be available in 18 hours ((

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.

Comment: This code does not work any longer. It still hides fields perfectly, however it does not take down "require" from them.

Comment: @MarcinRutkowski well originally OP didn't ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution this solution is also a working on many criteria.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields');

function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
$shipping_method ='free_shipping:1'; // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
global $woocommerce;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']); // Add/change filed name to be hide
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
}
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if you read my question again, you will see that I need to specify multiple delivery methods. Also, my version of the code hides and shows fields using AJAX. That's why your code doesn't work for me.